# React Native no models show

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I would like to show modal when the user enabled the switch or disabled. what should i do to achieved what i want? this is my current code. I am new in this technology, I hope you all understand , Please bear with me. thanks

```
import {SimpleModal} from '../../components/modal/Modal';

const [isModalVisible, setisModalVisible] = useState(false);

const changeModalVisible=(bool) =>{
  setisModalVisible(bool);
}

const confirmDelete = (id,status) =>{
  console.log("changeModalVisible: ",changeModalVisible(true))
  if (status == 0){
    if (changeModalVisible(false)) {
      handleDelete(id,status);
    } else {
      alert("error")
    }
  }else{
    if (changeModalVisible(true)) {
      handleActivate(id,status);
    } else {

    }
  }
}
<FlatList
    keyExtractor={(item, index) =>index.toString()}
    data={documentlists}
    renderItem={({ item }) => (
    <DocumentLocation
         key={item.name}
         status={item.status}
         editHandler={handleEdit}
         pressHandler={confirmDelete}
     />
   )}
/>
<Modal
    transparent={true}
    animationType='fade'
    visible={isModalVisible}
    nRequestClose={() => changeModalVisible(false)}
></Modal>
<SimpleModal/>
```

component/model/Model.js

```
    const SimpleModal = () => {
    return (
        <TouchableOpacity
            disabled={true}
            style={formStyles.container}
        >
            <View>
                <View>
                    <Text>
                        Sample modal header
                    </Text>
                    <Text>
                        Sample modal description
                    </Text>
                </View>
            </View>
        </TouchableOpacity>
    )
}
```

work flow, if the client switch the toggle popup modal will appear,
in the modal, i want two button that is **ok** and **cancel**, if the user click the **ok**, the data will updated and if **cancel**,  no updated data, note the functionality of updating data is already working, my problem is the modal , please refer to this image

[image]

Comment: Are you trying to have a confirm delete ?

Comment: yes and activate account,

Comment: So flow would be use press the switch -> modal is shown with yes/no and toggle status updated based on that ?

Comment: exactly @GuruparanGiritharan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per your comment this is the flow you expect.

1. User clicks switch in flatlist
2. If the value is false the status is updated
3. If value is true, a confirmation Modal is shown.

There are some changes required

```
 renderItem={({ item,index }) => (
    <DocumentLocation
         key={item.name}
         status={item.status}
         editHandler={handleEdit}
         pressHandler={(value)=>confirmDelete(value,index)}
     />
   )}
```

Here the value should come from the switch

instead of using the showModalVisible have a state to manage the selectedIndex

```
const [selectedIndex, setSelectedIndex] = useState(-1);
```

If an item is changed to true we set the selectedIndex

We use that to control the visibility of the modal

```
<Modal visible={selectedIndex > -1} onRequestClose={() => setSelectedIndex(-1)}>
  <Text>Approve?</Text>
  <Button
    title="Yes"
    onPress={() => {
      updateSelectedItem(selectedIndex, true);
      setSelectedIndex(-1);
    }}
  />
  <Button title="No" onPress={() => setSelectedIndex(-1)} />
</Modal>
```

The buttons in the Modal will rest the selected index or update the array.Something like the below function.

```
  const updateSelectedItem = (index, value) => {
    const updatedData = [...data];
    updatedData[index].active = value;
    setData(updatedData);
  };
```

Sample code
https://snack.expo.io/@guruparan/verifypopup

Comment: ReferenceError: value is not defined

Comment: You should pass the value from the switch, see my sample code

Answer (score 0):

You should enclose your `SimpleModal` component in the `Modal`, like this -

```
<Modal
    transparent={true}
    animationType='fade'
    visible={isModalVisible}
    nRequestClose={() => changeModalVisible(false)}
>
    <SimpleModal/>
</Modal>
```

Answer (score 0):

for modals use https://github.com/jeremybarbet/react-native-modalize

this library saved me a lot of days and pain developing modals in my app

if you are not using typescript, change the ref from

`const modalizeRef = useRef<Modalize>(null);`

to

`const modalizeRef = useRef(null);`